# Possible to get physical keyboard layout for a on-screen keyboard?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm currently working on a on-screen keyboard for a touchscreen app.

I wonder if anyone have experience on how the keyplacement shall look? (Unicode, on other languages like Japanese, Korean, Norwegian, Swedish etc) Finished layouts etc...

I found this info regarding layout/scancodes: http://www.quadibloc.com/comp/scan.htm

If I build a 101/102/106-keyboards after this layout, with scancode 3 range, will it look "correct" physically for most people? Even when someone earlier stated that it is 150 keyboard layouts out there *gasp*, so I guess it wouldn't please all.

Microsoft have their own layout lists here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/bb964651
The U+xxxx is virtualcodes, are there any tables like U+0031 (number 1) is the [x,y] -> [1, 0] position in a keyboard?

Thanks for any suggestion/help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Israel, and I can help you with Hebrew lay-out if you need it. But that Microsoft site you posted looks pretty much enough

Answer (score 0):

Do consult with locals on how the keyboard actually works. I've seen some where the thing printed on the right-hand side works with the right alt or with some other odd key. If you get that wrong the user is going to be very confused still.